# ACF Wordpress slow when using object for get default value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF plugin and when there have no value set i'm using this code to get default value of that field and show

```
echo do_shortcode(get_field_object('field_64214332b643a')['default_value']);
```

but this seems really slow it affecting time to first byte too, we usign redis cache and total cache both but both not caching when visitors with query string.
i guess when we load lots of other data also loads, can anyone know a alternative to access the default value of given field please. like using wp query or something, just need to access original acf object default value.

Comment: You could go and check how this default value is stored in the database, and make your own custom query instead ... not sure if that will be any faster though. Have you first of all actually _verified_ that it is the `get_field_object` call, that slows things down here? Not maybe the shortcode itself?

Comment: The only big success I've had with wordpress, ACF and speed is when you match with [Redis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) or Memcache,

Comment: Actually, surely the default value should be provided when using the standard `get_field` function? that's what makes it a default value?

Comment: we have above redis plugin but still having issue also the get_field not have original default value